# Asp.Net 5 image gets killed/stopped on Linux VM after 3-4 seconds of working

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

I have successfully installed docker on Linux VM and started sample from git.

Now I want to run my procject. So I created image (which was built successfully) using command:

> docker build -t versaweb .

And when I start it with command:

> docker run -t -d -p 80:5003 versaweb

and when cheking using docker ps it is running but when 3 or 4 second of up time passes i check again with docker ps and it's gone. When I run project on windows machine it works flawlessly - so I belive I have something wrong in project.json or in docker.

Here is my project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "bundleExclude": "*.cmd",
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta3",
        "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-beta3", // For Mono.
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Cache.Memory": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta3"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
        "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5003"

    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Utilities": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["kpm", "restore"]
EXPOSE 5003
ENTRYPOINT ["k", "kestrel"]
```

If someone who has experience with this could help me I would really appreciate this :)

Comment: I believe that ASP.Net only supports linux using the core framework; you'll need to switch from `aspnet50` to `aspnetcore50`.

Comment: I'll have access to VM tommorow and It'll be first thing I'll do.

Comment: Are there any logs that you can share?

Comment: Also, if there are logs, please set the `K_TRACE` to 1 prior to running the application so we can get more information

Comment: After changing to 

    aspnetcore50 

I have some assembly refference issues eg. SslStream,Linq,Tasks etc. not found

Comment: I have difficult time getting logs ... could you instruct me on how to obtain them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it was't stopped or killed It just did not start. After I used docker run without flag -d

> docker run -t -p (...)

I could see the log and what was wrong. It turned out that my ASP.Net5 Class Library was the problem - after I removed it from the project I could start the image. I am Still going to map it tomorrow morning so I'll edit answer with info about how It works.

PS: I had also problems with docker. Use newest versions. Below 1.7 there were problems with memory leaks.